# Why do I have a fail validation with mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, object

I'm new on mongodb, I have read documentation and I try to insert a document page with referenced id's of other documents but I have a validation fail.
That's my schema validation rules :

```js
db.createCollection("page", {
    capped: true,
    size: 4500000000,
        max: 6,
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            required: [ "title", "url", "elements" ],
            additionalProperties: false,
            properties: {
                title: {
                    bsonType: "object",
                    required: [ "content_id" ],
                    properties: {
                        content_id: {
                            bsonType: "objectId"
                        }
                    }
                },
                url: {
                    bsonType: "string"
                },
                elements: {
                    bsonType: "array",
                    items: {
                        bsonType: "object",
                        required: [ "order" , "element_id" ],
                        properties: {
                            order: {
                                bsonType: "int"
                            },
                            element_id: {
                                bsonType: "objectId"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And this is what i try to insert (i add in variable the futur id Object and variable content and document already have the id's i need)

```js
var page1 = ObjectId();

db.page.insertOne(
    {
        "_id": page1,
        "title": {
            "content_id": content5
        },
        "url": "/home",
        "elements": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "element_id": element1
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "element_id": element2
            },
            {
                "order": 3,
                "element_id": element3
            },
            {
                "order": 4,
                "element_id": element4
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

Please why do I have this error? I don't understand what the problem is, is this schema good with what I'm trying to insert?

```js
2020-04-07T18:55:35.513+0200 E  QUERY    [js] WriteError({
        "index" : 0,
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation",
        "op" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e8c72698d808f037e6adede"),
                "title" : {
                        "content_id" : ObjectId("5e8c72128d808f037e6aded6")
                },
                "url" : "/home",
                "elements" : [
                        {
                                "order" : 1,
                                "element_id" : ObjectId("5e8c724d8d808f037e6adeda")
                        },
                        {
                                "order" : 2,
                                "element_id" : ObjectId("5e8c724d8d808f037e6adedb")
                        },
                        {
                                "order" : 3,
                                "element_id" : ObjectId("5e8c724d8d808f037e6adedc")
                        },
                        {
                                "order" : 4,
                                "element_id" : ObjectId("5e8c724d8d808f037e6adedd")
                        }
                ]
        }
}) :
WriteError({
        "index" : 0,
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation",
        "op" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e8c72698d808f037e6adede"),
                "title" : {
                        "content_id" : ObjectId("5e8c72128d808f037e6aded6")
                },
                "url" : "/home",
                "elements" : [
                        {
                                "order" : 1,
                                "element_id" : ObjectId("5e8c724d8d808f037e6adeda")
                        },
                        {
                                "order" : 2,
                                "element_id" : ObjectId("5e8c724d8d808f037e6adedb")
                        },
                        {
                                "order" : 3,
                                "element_id" : ObjectId("5e8c724d8d808f037e6adedc")
                        },
                        {
                                "order" : 4,
                                "element_id" : ObjectId("5e8c724d8d808f037e6adedd")
                        }
                ]
        }
})
WriteError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:458:48
mergeBatchResults@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:855:49
executeBatch@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:919:13
Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1163:21
DBCollection.prototype.insertOne@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:264:9
@(shell):1:1
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Sometimes there can be some confusion between int / long. Try with bsontype 'number' instead of 'int', it will embrace all type of number (int/long/double) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#json-schema

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just tried and it returns the same error

Comment: I tried removing the order property to see if that's the problem, but it's the same thing with no order required when I insert it, I think it's my array of objects but I didn't the mistake : / Is this the right way to verify an array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got the solution, the problem was the additional rule Properties. So if it's on false, you have to add the _id property before inserting data because it considers _id as an additional property.

The bsonType: "int" can also make an error, so use number.

So with this validator rule i can insert my data ->

```js
db.createCollection("page", {
    capped: true,
    size: 4500000000,
        max: 6,
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            required: [ "_id", "title", "url", "elements" ],
            additionalProperties: false,
            properties: {
                _id: {
                    bsonType: "objectId"
                },
                title: {
                    bsonType: "object",
                    required: [ "content_id" ],
                    properties: {
                        content_id: {
                            bsonType: "objectId"
                        }
                    }
                },
                url: {
                    bsonType: "string"
                },
                elements: {
                    bsonType: "array",
                    items: {
                        bsonType: "object",
                        required: [ "order" , "element_id" ],
                        properties: {
                            order: {
                                bsonType: "number"
                            },
                            element_id: {
                                bsonType: "objectId"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```